# phpmyadmin MySQL data stored as ascii values in certain table

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

my host has just updated phpmyadmin to version 4.0.3. I don't know if it is related to the following problem.

I have a table 'users' which stores user data for the site and all data is now being stored as numbers. Where I had a username of 'rich' it is now '72696368' which is it's ascii code.

Any ideas why this might have happened? I have a lot of tables and have checked them all, it is only the users table that has been modified. It is not critical as I can still log in and accept new users etc but I would like to know why this is happening.

Thanks a lot

EDIT The collation is utf8_general_c

Answer (score 0):

try adding this snippet to the script you are running in the line in which you create the schema

```
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

for example :

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `my_schema` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: thanks for the response. The character set is already utf8. I should have stated that in the question.